# Monitor http request in Opera extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera

How can i monitor a request to a particular webpage in opera extension?
   for example if a request is sent to `*://*.example.com/change.php*` i would like to update     a variable.
Also can i monitor a request to a particular webpage using javascript alone?Please let me know.

ThankYou.

Answer (score 0):

The [Opera URL filter API](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/extensions-api-urlfilter/) will help. You can also read the article about [Site blocking with Opera’s URL Filter API](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/site-blocking-with-operas-url-filter-api/) with code examples.

Comment: Yes, but it is used to add and remove sites to a virtual block list and mostly it is ineffective,once you add or remove a website from the list you have to clear the browser's cache for the changes to take effect.

Comment: do you have a more detailed description of what you would like to do and maybe pieces of code. That would help.

Comment: Sorry for delay.Im trying to create a extension which blocks certain requests from facebook.for example during user chat in facebook whenever a user has seen a message , facebbok will notify the other user by `Seen at 4:12` by sending a request to a particular page.If we block this request user's privacy is maintained.